# Why isn't a datepicker appearing on my Rails text field?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 and JQuery 1.12.  I’m trying to make a field on my form a date picker field, but the date picker isn’t coming up.  I have this in my form …

```
    <%= f.text_field :day, :class => 'datepicker' %>
```

And here are the contents of my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file …

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

here is what is in my `app/assets/javascripts/my_objects.coffee` file …

```
jQuery ->
  $('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

But when I visit my page, `app/views/my_objects/index.html.erb`, and click on the form field above, there is no date picker rendered, it just remains a text field.  What else do I need to do or should be checking for to get my date picker to appear?

**Edit:**

In response to the answer given, I edited my “./app/assets/javascripts/my_objects.coffee” file to be exactly what you specified, but it doesn’t look like it is getting included in the page.  Here’s the header part of my page

```
                          <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/scaffolds.self-f7b997caf712f3060ad616e13504564b0a9628b98eaf796c98a22c85e4807b99.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/user_exercises.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-0cdb26a7c4fa73ae0385edcbf33f42655e1cf7078850c34ca7bc3a92df7e66b4.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.self-c64a74367bda6ef8b860f19e74df08927ca99d2be2ac934e9e92d5fd361e0da4.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-d602bdfe68ffc63b9f9cc512872aa3cfff046228a0a36e90dd476e8ef54c1b09.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-mocks.self-caf46ebee7d161f24a55382f8efda396a5c5c51d1fecb1055514134caa289cb3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular.self-3baa2c9049766d4c7aa7f91d102516dcb1c41428510e6bab431bf04d95e5731d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-1.12.0.min.self-9973772584f113d55d9de9e38305bede3c581ab45775c5ce1fc666aa5bf261a0.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/my_objects.self-58781860b9e8e33e3649547649f23837598175df0c9b8c42ac4e6c6d42738300.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-3b8dabdc891efe46b9a144b400ad69e37d7e5876bdc39dee783419a69d7ca819.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="g74gSb3nEz2qOL5zPN5Ai/x+2xEafx5be5X1mkILOEAJWFu/lgqMyog6vUGIKeehDmFBj1gDv67qeVI5DUE+yg==" />
</head>
<body>
```

The date picker isn’t coming up when I click on the text field and I suspect that’s because the coffee stuff ins’t getting included anywhere.

**Edit 2:**

K, I updated my Gemfile, did "bundle install" and then edited my application.js file to include the ui, so now my header looks like the below ...

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>PushUp Moose</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/scaffolds.self-f7b997caf712f3060ad616e13504564b0a9628b98eaf796c98a22c85e4807b99.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/user_exercises.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-0cdb26a7c4fa73ae0385edcbf33f42655e1cf7078850c34ca7bc3a92df7e66b4.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
      <script src="/assets/jquery.self-c64a74367bda6ef8b860f19e74df08927ca99d2be2ac934e9e92d5fd361e0da4.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/core.self-93be4d22eda916787802a64d8f88b52db8a9027d4ccbbc0942625324a7d12d44.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self-c1602241ddc51216b58391768667068867b8e15b9efc722befcd25771eda6819.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/accordion.self-c95f320275150a94241b004a91e21eef9c5ae9965a793cb3e2475f6078a1670d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/position.self-e693ced4ecfa1a276f0b794f32c1d30d792764b08788bf68ecfa3b388c291333.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/menu.self-7abc1c9401509a7e4fc609b1e461be6fd17e8116e8fda19cc59d05ba79aefb68.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/autocomplete.self-3befc48aba87cead090cfd014562b2771a662ac6d2c8197b24c08b2d9f3d9f2d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/button.self-4d4f21ba77bbf8cc08ae65e2b6329a7a1b952b32c3ba7bffca8313e7e8c93d0c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.self-6267be6d4d0f0e8665be3b4d6ac07f40ba23a32aff8eaa5d1bfc00f76a9eeae7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/mouse.self-c513294e8da73f31f84ba3ef11e2a1180a47faea0eb2fea4a53fc26153dd21fd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/draggable.self-debcca3d0d5d9afe2fe91a6fd1aebdb41ca0a55f2f6017352e6c02b6d8a6e64c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/resizable.self-60b870565f3cd62982c1907828119bb51f42ec8228d5e23868153edc3abc685c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/dialog.self-5a6c7980dfa3f6b74445b0f4b20eed799ee65363163500ed7f032e603d6b022d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/droppable.self-a7a2b4c2cec8fc176f51e4e4291d92bfd3eec40b6a580b47fc54c16334d52882.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect.self-3acdb29e7da09c8f0195b994d2f04d73bfef50dc539c84fd2c835d964d33e5c1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-blind.self-ed102209d7aa0b7374f3db8478cc7dcff5f9980d3146e8bf9fbfab959c6d5d8a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-bounce.self-bfcb9288797ecd234ddeedf4fbc5b4c9de94a4e6d8d44e6faa5b5e9836fad9fd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-clip.self-7368e4597c32360b162d264ff8bbd0cf9fb1535eb9b4564e6eb7c1db3c774bf3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-drop.self-294aaa72126ad9c94d6558cca792eb3716754713aca98f18a9dd7c493150ed92.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-explode.self-68e74dc114a52f3f4d7033e40c39196961bdcf439652daa2e98baa115c7bb44b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-fade.self-42d542a5253e0a610717460102ee6bee339c656cc188e491d89eb0779043c963.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-fold.self-ad9967f153423916300dbf1104b00f7ad7bbd6a222a0fcc1012ebe251bcb13c8.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-highlight.self-f922b7179ab8ccfa7865141f38865bba0a3d2bdceba7561c27ca14544dbfd996.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-size.self-368aecefa09656a2be5c72dc8e685b120363a3df812134cbd2dd998bafa179fd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-scale.self-884a5abcb6d90fcd9f9a071aa8329638184df688afced1b1d3b6be6c69f4dd7f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-puff.self-93415831093923a70f671d73e8d0b3d94deb37ac7472a036a4add545f565c166.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-pulsate.self-eb107c0d136eccdfbd8a2f0f2ee71e0f6911cb300c6b63cc2fe4f6532e6a9a97.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-shake.self-63bcc14897aac5b84e10690be94d64d5724f864aa14c913b4d1030c461a256ad.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-slide.self-c93054a4a80d1f986760806d81ab067e4a4120bf103337e152ecc24d36e785f6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-transfer.self-181245634ec522320fc1081f6dbf94fd982f34eefa03555f76817dedfcdea336.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/progressbar.self-a259ff5a2a5e7aef0ec21bda94edd0f6bc1e9821128d901de415956edf212b0d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/selectable.self-42e53fc2f95211314e36a8094c42560f869c207f16d68cfc206aa37201dcdc03.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/selectmenu.self-09dbcac573f0e508194bd9deff254db090889b380d030261857860309c0918e8.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/slider.self-8af8d2a0661743ba88b4cfb99d5c8c874cfa3fc6528ae4e9252366b388def0b7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/sortable.self-df2d80a36f9dfbe0facc596ccd92af83ca50d38e4cd6a84810aaf5d40b8cd181.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/spinner.self-3c8c95a7bc9c877d0f9c16789246bbedda6b8e8fbf5927951babdab775aed02e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/tabs.self-dc07b44bf1b926c8d28ccd2658e30933881e5329348caf70cf305c3943f6bbd7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui/tooltip.self-38f04ac3a6c8fb2391ec6832b68845671cc9013a94371b7eb239478f4835eb73.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui.self-52111578aa54225c9ebfe06f78a62771020ee548bb27d62228ee3f5e6633969d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-d602bdfe68ffc63b9f9cc512872aa3cfff046228a0a36e90dd476e8ef54c1b09.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-1.12.0.min.self-9973772584f113d55d9de9e38305bede3c581ab45775c5ce1fc666aa5bf261a0.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/user_exercises.self-58781860b9e8e33e3649547649f23837598175df0c9b8c42ac4e6c6d42738300.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.self-f8806224e027f3e3f0138ea9ce99319e298dfdb323304d1f1be6eae8e8c74724.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
      <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="444pM8jiudnL+FYACTvWVBXBuaOc2WfGUmqzBQGy0oxpaFLF4w8mLun6VTK9zHF+594jPd6lxjPDhhSmTvjUBg==" />
    </head>
    <body>i
```

But I get this JS exception upon refreshing my page, "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function" on this line

Comment: are you loading in `my_objects.coffee`? it needs to be required as well..

Comment: Which `datepicker` gem or JS library are you using?

Comment: @virtuexru not true, `//= require_tree .` requires it as well.

Comment: if you reload the page let's say if you press `Ctrl + R` does the datepicker appears?

Comment: Did my answer work for you? let us know, please consider mark my answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm on Mac Yosemite, using Chrome and clicking "Ctrl + R" does nothing.  Reloading the page does not make the datepicker appear on the text field.  @smathy, I'm not using any gem, I'm trying to use the JQuery datepicker library.

Comment: Your file is included indeed: `<script src="/assets/my_objects.self-58781860b9e8e33e3649547649f23837598175df0c9b8c42ac4e6c6d42738300.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>`

Comment: Let me ask you something are you testing your date picker in development or in production? is your app deployed to heroku or something like that?

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Also did you check that your form field has the right class `.datepicker`?

Comment: Please do the following, make a `console.log 'hello world'` in your coffee file, and reload the page, check in the javascript console if the text is printed out

Comment: Hi, Yes my form field has teh datepicker class, and yes there is a JS error in hte console, which I have included in my second edit.  Thanks for your help, - Dave

Comment: Well great, however my answer deserves at least a thumbs up, since it guided you to the real issue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the new information you've provided I think I have identified your problem.

You said in your comment that you're trying to use the jQuery Datepicker, and yet as you've shown in your `application.js` and in the corresponding `<script>` tags in your HTML you're not including the correct library anyway.

The `Datepicker` doesn't automatically come with `jquery.js`, you have to add `jquery-ui.js` to your project.

You can confirm this yourself by opening your Javascript debugging window and reloading your page. In Chrome on OSX you open the JS debug window by typing: ⌥⌘J and you reload the page with: ⌘R  When you do you should see an error something like: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function` - that's because Chrome can't find the `datepicker` function because you don't have `jquery-ui` in your project.

### The Fix

The easiest way to get `jquery-ui` in your project is to add this line in your `Gemfile` if it's not already there:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Then run `bundle install` to install the gem.

And then, as per [the README](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) for the gem, add this to your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

You'll need to put it **after** the `require jquery` line.

Btw, you **will** still want to change the event you run that `datepicker` on as @SsouLlesS suggests so it's compatible with turbolinks page loading.

Comment: Hi, I've ipmlemented your suggestions, and I can see the Jquery UI included in the page (see my second edit), but alas, upon loading the page, I get the JS error, "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function" and my date picker does not appear alongside my text field.

Comment: You sure you're not getting confused by the errors from the previous load? The debugging console doesn't clear itself between refreshes. If you see the `<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.self-...js">` link in your HTML then the datepicker function **is** loaded.

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure.  In the interactive console if I type, "$('.datepicker')", I get "Object[input#my_object_day.datepicker property value = "" attribute value = "null"]", but when I type, "$('.datepicker').datepicker();", I get "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function".

Comment: Is the jquery-ui supposed to appear before the jquery library?  My feeling is no, but I don't know how to control the order in which they appear.

Comment: It's meant to appear after, and that's what you're showing it as, although I see that you have `jquery-1.12.0.min` after the `jquery-ui`. You also marked my answer as accepted, did you work out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a Turbolinks issue, I can deduct that due to the way you are calling your `datepicker()` in your .coffee file

the solution is to call your `document.ready` code during the `page:change` event. Here is the code you can use:

`app/assets/javascripts/my_objects.coffee`

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', -> $('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

## Update

Your issue is not with turbo links, however you were going to have problems with turbo links anyways in the way you were calling the script.

Ok your script is indeed included, then try the following:

Rename your file from `my_objects.coffee` to `my_objects.js.coffee`, this may be causing issues with the Uglifier compiler.

For ensure that your file is indeed running and your issue could be with date picker only, then run a `console.log` then check the javascript console of the browser for see if the text is printed out, that way we can discard that the code in your file is not being executed

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', -> console.log 'This is running!'
```

If you can see the text printed in the console, then check if your textfield is correctly rendered with the `.datepicker` class.

Check that your application.js file is unique and there is not any duplicates like: application.coffee

For avoid this issue in development, then precompile assets before deployment:

`rake assets:precompile`

Then commit changes and deploy.

Comment: Hi, I changed the coffee file to be the code you included here but the datepicker still isn't coming up.  I have put the header of my page in an edit to my question.  I don't see you're code included on my page when it is rendered so I wonder if I have to do more to get that coffee file included.